# How can i write "AND" in bold using below code, I am not able to write html tag inside condition

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is the code. Where i want to AND in bold so i was trying to use html tag

```
var stri = " <strong>" + 'AND' + "</strong> "
```

Its print the html tag in browser.

Output- `<strong>AND</strong>`

```
if( filterArray.length > 0 ){
        var filterText = "";
        _.each( filterArray, function(fObj, index){
          filterText += fObj.title + " " + (fObj.filterType === "include" ? "IN" : (fObj.filterType === "exclude" ? "NOT IN" : "CONTAIN")) + " " + "[ ";
          if( fObj.values.length > 1 ) {
            var stri = "AND "
            filterText += "" + fObj.values[0] + " and " + String(fObj.values.length - 1) + " more ] " + " " + (index !== filterArray.length - 1 ? stri : "");
          }
          else {
            var stri = "AND "
            filterText += "" + fObj.values[0] + " ] " + " " + (index !== filterArray.length - 1 ? stri : "");
          }
        });
        return filterText.substring(0, filterText.length - 2);
      }
      else {
        return "-";
      }
```

Comment: How are you inserting the resulting text into your HTML?

Comment: I do not see a usage of `<strong>` in the snippet as described by the lead up text.

Comment: Assuming that code does what it should and you use the line you mentioned, you need to insert the result using something like `$(...).html(result);` in order to make the browser parse the html: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/ohy7szqu/

Comment: Actually that may be an issue injected by the edits.  So I'll repeat my first post.  Text nodes on their own cannot be stylized different from their sibling text nodes.  They have to be in a tag, such as a span, to have their own styling.

Comment: The code here is probably not the cause of the problem. It's how you insert the generated string in your page that matters. With jQuery, `element.text(string)` will display the text exactly as is, whereas `element.html(string)` will render it as HTML.

Comment: So this is printed all text in same div I only want to bold AND but not able to find the solution I tried above thing with jquery can we get the solution using angularJS

Comment: *It prints the html tag in browser* - certainly sounds like you're using `.text(str)` instead of `.html(str)` - but as that part hasn't been included, it's only conjecture.   Please update your question with a snippet that *demonstrates* the problem (or at a minimum include how you add it to the page).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example